# How do I use onChange function to reset a field in Odoo11? (Barcode Scan)

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

there is a **barcode** field (type: char) in my module, and it holds the **scanned barcode value** of a product that scanned by using a **barcode scanner**. This scanned product will be added to the **line** field(type: one 2 many) in in the **POS order**. After this, the **barcode** field should be get cleared for the next product's barcode. **This work in Odoo10** but, it's not working in Odoo11. In Odoo11, for the working of onchange, we have to change the value in that Barcode field and press enter or click on save button and edit. Then it will work. But, I need after the scan, that field should be get cleared.
 I have given a piece of code below. Waiting for the right solution. Thanks in Advance. :)

```py
class PosOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = "pos.order"

    barcode = fields.Char('Product')

    @api.multi
    @api.onchange('barcode')
    def _onchange_barcode(self):
        for record in self:
            #my codes
            record.barcode = ""
            print ("Value in Barcode field is ",record.barcode,". Have nice time")
```

The above code will print the following line in the terminal:
 *Value in Barcode field is  . Have nice time*
It sets the barcode field as blank but, it will not affect in the front end. I have attached a screenshot with this.
[image]

Comment: Hi, did you get solution for this issue ?